# Logging from within a coded UI test

Tags: .net, logging, coded-ui-tests

I've been writing Coded UI Tests using Visual Studio 2012, and have a question regarding logging from within a test.

I've done some research on this, and most articles point me over to the `EqtTraceLevel` switch you can enable in your `App.config`.  This instructs the test runner to basically dump each step to an HTML file, complete with a little screen cap.  Way cool.

What I'd like to be able to do is create my own custom log entries, which would preferably be available in the same HTML log file, or within a separate log file in the same folder.  One thing I noticed is the `TestContext::WriteLine()` method, which seems to write trace messages while the test is running.  However, I added the line:

```
context.WriteLine("Database provisioned for test: {0}", dbName);
```

Within my `[ClassInitialize]` method.  However, I don't see this trace message appearing in any log file I can find, nor do I see it in the Debug window within Visual Studio.  So, I'm not entirely sure what this method is supposed to do.

What's the recommended way to create custom log entries within a coded UI test that are then available after the test runs?  Or, should I just configure something like NLog or Log4Net and just have it output to the same directory as the other logs?

**Update:**

Made a little bit of progress.  It turns out, `TestContext::WriteLine()` works, but only within a `[TestMethod]`.  It does *not* work within a `[ClassInitialize]`.  Anything I write with `WriteLine` will appear in the Test Output within Visual Studio, so I assume there's some sort of way to configure the test runner to dump that out to a file.  This seems a bit limited, especially since my test setup and teardown is rather complex and involves provisioning databases and stuff; I'd really like to have some sort of logging if thing go wrong.  I'm guessing the answer is to use a third party logging library.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Writing message in Coded UI HtmlLogger output file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23951320/writing-message-in-coded-ui-htmllogger-output-file)